# How to change Home Folder from Remote to default local path?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

[image]

H, dear all i need help question about how to configure my home folder path on Macbook into default local path cause i just see that my home folder is shown that it's Remote Alias i have no idea about this?

First of all, I have to said that I have no less knowledge about coding but this situation it's a must that i need to learn it to fixed my problem now.

I really need to do this because right now everything on MacbookAir is seem like control by Remote Server cause I see so many activities shows that it's Remote process but I never done that myself !

Comment: Configure in what? Macs don't have a home folder actually called 'home'. The home folder is the one with your user name, inside the one in the picture called 'Users'.

Comment: Then what the home folder in the photo is mean to?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Hmmm… it appears I *do* also have one, not marked 'remote' & completely empty. I have no clue what it's for. I found this - https://superuser.com/questions/524632/what-is-home-directory-in-mac-os-used-for [which seems to also think it has no real purpose.]

Comment: I've added an answer, but please [edit] your question with why you want to do this?

Answer (score -1):

> 1. edit  `/etc/auto_master` # comment out the line with /home in it.
> 2. remount:
>
>    `sudo automount -vc`

3. disable System Integrity Protection by rebooting to recovery (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on startup) and `csrutil disable`
4. delete `/home`

> 5. make a softlink to the mac-ified dir:
>
>    `sudo ln -s $HOME  /home/$USER`

[How can I use the /home directory on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558272/1549818)

Comment: This is no longer a thing, if it ever was.  There needs to be a vote undo, too.

Comment: I have do command you suggest but terminal show this message: ln: ./home: Read-only file system

Comment: @leeannecando There is no reason to do the above.

Comment: @Marc I don't understand, it works fine for me and step 2 prints `automount: /System/Volumes/Data/home unmounted`. Sure, this all seems pointless without context that I've asked for in the question's comments, but I don't see anything wrong with the answer itself?

Comment: @grg I shouldn't have downvoted it, but there's no reason to make this change, so the OP really should answer your question as to why.

Comment: @MarcWilson I can not run any command It will show I have no permission even I run as root